# Make Label Visible if TextBox has a value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a label visible if a Textbox has a value. So far I have this but its not working?

```
Private Sub Label1_Change()

If MailChannel.Value <> "" Then
    Me.Label1.Caption = True
Else 
Me.Label1.Caption = False

 End If

 End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `Label1.Visible = True`?

Comment: Nope, doesn't work

Comment: Try using the TextBox1_Change not the Label_change, with the .Visible that Jacob H said

Answer (score 0):

Your current code won't be triggered now, because it is linked to form's label. You should link it to textbox change event. It can be realized as follows (assuming that textbox name is txtMailChannel):

```
            Private Sub txtMailChannel_Change()
                If txtMailChannel.Value <> "" Then
                    lblMailChannel.Visible = True
                Else
                    lblMailChannel.Visible = False
                End If
            End Sub
```

P.S. Try to introduce some order to your code, especially what concerns naming convention of variables. Please check-out the following link for references: https://github.com/spences10/VBA-Coding-Standards.